# Rust - Collecting slices of a Vec in a recursive function

Tags: recursion, rust, lifetime, huffman-code, ownership

I am currently trying to build a huffman encoding program and am struggling with a problem I have while traversing my generated huffman tree to create a lookup table. I decided to implement said traversal with a recursive function. In the actual implementation I use the [bitvec](https://crates.io/crates/bitvec) crate to save bitsequences, but for simplicitly I will use `Vec<bool>` in this post.

The idea I had was to save a collection of all codewords in the `Vec` `codewords` and then only save a slice out of that vector for the actual lookup table, for which I used a `HashMap`.

The issue is how exactly I would solve adding a 0 or a 1 for both the left and right traversal. My idea here was to save a clone of a slice of the current sequence, append a 0 to `codewords`, then append that clone to the end of `codewords` after traversing to the left so that I can push a 1 and traverse to the right. The function I came up with looks like this:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

// ignore everything being public, I use getters in the real code
pub struct HufTreeNode {
    pub val: u8,
    pub freq: usize,
    pub left: i16,
    pub right: i16,
}

fn traverse_tree<'a>(
    cur_index: usize,
    height: i16,
    codewords: &'a mut Vec<bool>,
    lookup_table: &mut HashMap<u8, &'a [bool]>,
    huffman_tree: &[HufTreeNode],
) {
    let cur_node = &huffman_tree[cur_index];

    // if the left child is -1, we reached a leaf
    if cur_node.left == -1 {
        // the last `height` bits in codewords
        let cur_sequence = &codewords[(codewords.len() - 1 - height as usize)..];
        lookup_table.insert(cur_node.val, cur_sequence);
        return;
    }

    // save the current sequence so we can traverse to the right afterwards
    let mut cur_sequence = codewords[(codewords.len() - 1 - height as usize)..].to_vec();
    codewords.push(false);
    traverse_tree(
        cur_node.left as usize,
        height + 1,
        codewords, // mutable borrow - argument requires that `*codewords` is borrowed for `'a`
        lookup_table,
        huffman_tree,
    );

    // append the previously saved current sequence
    codewords.append(&mut cur_sequence); // second mutable borrow occurs here
    codewords.push(true); // third mutable borrow occurs here
    traverse_tree(
        cur_node.right as usize,
        height + 1,
        codewords, // fourth mutable borrow occurs here
        lookup_table,
        huffman_tree,
    );
}

fn main() {
    // ...
}
```

Apparently there is an issue with lifetimes and borrowing in that snippet of code, and I kind of get what the problem is. From what I understand, when I give `codewords` as a parameter in the recursive call, it has to borrow the vector for as long as I save the slice in `lookup_table` which is obviously not possible, causing the error. How do I solve this?

This is what `cargo check` gives me:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*codewords` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> untitled.rs:43:5
   |
14 |   fn traverse_tree<'a>(
   |                    -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
34 | /     traverse_tree(
35 | |         cur_node.left as usize,
36 | |         height + 1,
37 | |         codewords, // mutable borrow - argument requires that `*codewords` is borrowed for `'a`
   | |         --------- first mutable borrow occurs here
38 | |         lookup_table,
39 | |         huffman_tree,
40 | |     );
   | |_____- argument requires that `*codewords` is borrowed for `'a`
...
43 |       codewords.append(&mut cur_sequence); // second mutable borrow occurs here
   |       ^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here

error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*codewords` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> untitled.rs:44:5
   |
14 |   fn traverse_tree<'a>(
   |                    -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
34 | /     traverse_tree(
35 | |         cur_node.left as usize,
36 | |         height + 1,
37 | |         codewords, // mutable borrow - argument requires that `*codewords` is borrowed for `'a`
   | |         --------- first mutable borrow occurs here
38 | |         lookup_table,
39 | |         huffman_tree,
40 | |     );
   | |_____- argument requires that `*codewords` is borrowed for `'a`
...
44 |       codewords.push(true); // third mutable borrow occurs here
   |       ^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here

error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*codewords` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> untitled.rs:48:9
   |
14 |   fn traverse_tree<'a>(
   |                    -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
34 | /     traverse_tree(
35 | |         cur_node.left as usize,
36 | |         height + 1,
37 | |         codewords, // mutable borrow - argument requires that `*codewords` is borrowed for `'a`
   | |         --------- first mutable borrow occurs here
38 | |         lookup_table,
39 | |         huffman_tree,
40 | |     );
   | |_____- argument requires that `*codewords` is borrowed for `'a`
...
48 |           codewords, // fourth mutable borrow occurs here
   |           ^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
```

What am I missing here? Is there some magical function in the vector API that I'm missing, and why exactly does this create lifetime issues in the first place? From what I can tell, all my lifetimes are correct because `codewords` always lives for long enough for `lookup_table` to save all those slices and I never mutably borrow something twice at the same time. If there was something wrong with my lifetimes, the compiler would complain inside the `if cur_node.left == -1` block, and the `cur_sequence` I take after it is an owned `Vec`, so there can't be any borrowing issues with that. So the issue really is with the core idea of having a recursive function with a mutable reference as a parameter.

Is there any way for me to solve this? I tried making `codewords` owned and returning it, but then the compiler cannot ensure that the bitsequence I'm saving inside `lookup_table` lives for long enough. The only idea I still have is to save owned vectors inside `lookup_table`, but at that point the `codewords` vector is obselete in the first place and I can simply implement this by having a `cur_sequence` vector as parameter which I clone in every call, but I chose my approach for a better cache performance in the actual encoding process right after, which I would then lose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you create a slice `cur_sequence` from `codewords` like you did in `let cur_sequence = &codewords[(codewords.len() - 1 - height as usize)..];`, the compiler extends the lifetime of the reference to `codewords` to at least the same as `cur_sequence` (why: The compiler wants to ensure that the slice `cur_sequence` is always valid, but if you change `codewords` (say, clear it) then it's possible that `cur_sequence` is invalid. By keeping an immutable reference to `codewords`, then borrow rules will forbid modification of `codewords` when the slice is still alive). And unfortunately you save `cur_sequence` in `lookup_table`, thus keeping the reference to `codewords` alive all over the function, so you cannot mutably borrow `codewords` anymore.

The solution is to maintain the indexes of the slice by yourself: create a struct:

```
struct Range {
    start: usize,
    end: usize
}

impl Range {
    fn new(start: usize, end: usize) -> Self {
        Range{ start, end}
    }
}
```

then use it instead of the slices:

```
let cur_range = Range::new(
    codewords.len() - 1 - height as usize,
    codewords.len() - 1
);
lookup_table.insert(cur_node.val, cur_range);
```

In this way, the responsibility to keep the ranges valid is yours.

complete code:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

// ignore everything being public, I use getters in the real code
pub struct HufTreeNode {
    pub val: u8,
    pub freq: usize,
    pub left: i16,
    pub right: i16,
}

struct Range {
    start: usize,
    end: usize
}

impl Range {
    fn new(start: usize, end: usize) -> Self {
        Range{ start, end}
    }
}

fn traverse_tree(
    cur_index: usize,
    height: i16,
    codewords: &mut Vec<bool>,
    lookup_table: &mut HashMap<u8, Range>,
    huffman_tree: &[HufTreeNode],
) {
    let cur_node = &huffman_tree[cur_index];

    // if the left child is -1, we reached a leaf
    if cur_node.left == -1 {
        // the last `height` bits in codewords
        // let cur_sequence = &codewords[(codewords.len() - 1 - height as usize)..];
        let cur_range = Range::new(
            codewords.len() - 1 - height as usize,
            codewords.len() - 1
        );
        lookup_table.insert(cur_node.val, cur_range);
        return;
    }

    // save the current sequence so we can traverse to the right afterwards
    let mut cur_sequence = codewords[(codewords.len() - 1 - height as usize)..].to_vec();
    codewords.push(false);
    traverse_tree(
        cur_node.left as usize,
        height + 1,
        codewords, // mutable borrow - argument requires that `*codewords` is borrowed for `'a`
        lookup_table,
        huffman_tree,
    );

    // append the previously saved current sequence
    codewords.append(&mut cur_sequence); // second mutable borrow occurs here
    codewords.push(true); // third mutable borrow occurs here
    traverse_tree(
        cur_node.right as usize,
        height + 1,
        codewords, // fourth mutable borrow occurs here
        lookup_table,
        huffman_tree,
    );
}

fn main() {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I edited the original post so it is now (hopefully) self-containing.

But sadly this does not work. The slices I put in `lookup_table` are all coming from `codewords`. If I don't manually add the lifetimes, the compiler will give each reference its own lifetime and will then give an error when I try to insert the slice with `lookup_table.insert(...)` because the lifetimes I actually have don't match the function signature.